# How to test the second level of the api.send function

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am doing a test of a function that returns a promise and in turn calls the same method again but I don't know how to access the second level of call.

My function

```
itemToForm = () => {
        this.api.send(this.component, 'get', { lang: 'ES', filter: { id: this.item['id'] } }).then(resEsp => {
            this.item = resEsp['data'][0];
            this.api.send(this.component, 'get', { lang: 'EN', filter: { id: this.item['id'] } }).then(res => {
                let itemEng = res['data'][0]
                let fields = this.formDef
                    .map(register => register
                        .filter(field => field['register_table'].indexOf('traduction') !== -1)
                        .map(field => field['field_name'])
                    ).filter(register => register.length);

                fields = fields.length ? fields[0] : [];
                if (itemEng)
                    this.item = Object.keys(itemEng)
                        .reduce((obj, key) => {

                            obj[key] = this.item[key];
                            if (fields.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                                obj[key + '_eng'] = itemEng[key];
                            }

                            return obj
                        }, {})
                if (this.item) {
                    this.setForm();
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

I have the correct test of the first level, but when I mock for the second level, I don't know how to configure the spyOn for this call.

My test:

```
describe('itemToForm()', () => {
        it('should call api.send with resEsp', () => {
            let item = { id: 1, name: 'test' };
            component.component = 'Events';
            let resEsp = {
              data: [
                { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
                { id: 2, name: 'test2' },
                { id: 3, name: 'test3' }
              ]
            };
            component.item = item;

            //let spy1 = spyOn(api, 'send').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(resEsp));
            let spy1 = spyOn(api, 'send').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(resEsp));
            component.itemToForm();

            expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Events', 'get', { lang: 'ES', filter: { id: 1 } });
        });
        it('should call api.send with res Eng', () => {
          let itemEng = { id: 1, name: 'test', lang: 'EN' }
          component.component = 'Events';
          let resEsp = {data: [{ id: 1, name: 'test1' }, { id: 2, name: 'test2' }, { id: 3, name: 'test3' }]};
          let res = {data: [{ id: 1, name: 'test1' }, { id: 2, name: 'test2' }, { id: 3, name: 'test3' }]};
          component.item = itemEng;

          //let spy1 = spyOn(api, 'send').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(resEsp));
          let spy1 = spyOn(api, 'send').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(resEsp)).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(res));
          component.itemToForm();

          expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use returnValues instead to return multiple values in sequence.

```
let spy1 = spyOn(api, 'send').and.returnValues(Promise.resolve(resEsp), Promise.resolve(res));
```

https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValues%3C/code%3E